# How could I set loop bounds for a 2D array to split work by thread

Tags: c, multithreading

My goal is to create a multithreaded application using pthreads which accomplishes some task. The task and pthreads themselves are functioning correctly so I will not flood the screen with the several hundreds of lines of code and just show this important bit. Apologies if you wanted to test the code and this makes it difficult.

I unfortunately cannot figure out how to split up a 2D array to do the work in blocks by thread, as I am intended to do by this figure:

[image]

```
for(int i=(t_id%x)*(height/x); i<(t_id%x + 1)*(height/x); i++){
    for(int j=(t_id%x)*(length/x); j<(t_id%x + 1)*(length/x); j++){
        //some work is done
    }
}
//t_id -> thread id
//x -> 2^x = number of threads, so in this ex, x=4
//i -> y axis, j -> x-axis
//height -> bound on y-axis of array
//length -> bound on x-axis of array
```

Upon testing and inspection, it is obvious that this solution has a flaw in that all threads are placed along the diagonal. I can't quite figure out how to build a solution that gets around this. I would certainly appreciate any suggestions on how I could go about solving this issue.

Comment: I like to use [Work Partitioning](https://blogs.oracle.com/d/entry/partitioning_work_over_multiple_threads) as a guide. I use this to create row_start, row_end and col_start, col_end variables. The last section will also take care of border conditions too!

Then when you iterate in your for loops, iterate from row_start to row_end, incrementing by one, and the same for your inner loop but for columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have to split your grid to N rows and M columns. Than the thread working with a cell in the row I and column J would be working with data in range `H / N * I` to `H / N * (I + 1)` and `W / M * J` to `W / M * (J + 1)`, where I and J starts from 0.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So I get differentiating between rows and columns, I guess my problem is how to associate the thread id (in this example 0-15) with that I,J column mapping. Is it reasonable to suggest that the column would be (t_id % num_threads) and the row would be (t_id / num_threads)? From what I can tell this works, but I also thought that about my original solution so it's hard to say.

Comment: The `num_threads = N * M`. So `0 <= I < num_threads / M` and `0 <= J < M`